# Polymer 1.0. paper-tab stylization

Tags: polymer

I know about custom properties and mixins as well, but i need to stylize selected\unselected state of paper-tab. How i can to do it? I've used a following snippet:

```
--paper-tab: {
     color: var(--add-white-color);
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: var(--base-font-family);
     font-weight: 100;  
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

But it work only on unselected state of paper-tab. Also i tried to add the snippet used above in *paper-tab.iron-selected* selector. And this not helped. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style paper-tabs with simple css.

```
  paper-tab {
     color: green;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: courier;
     font-weight: 100;  
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }

  paper-tab.iron-selected {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

Here's [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rl6tzZgOwipMdjRwrVZP?p=preview)

**Note**: to styling the selection bar color can be done with a mixin

Comment: yes, thanks it's really work. I thought that this won't work when we set the "Shadow Dom" mode, but i was wrong:)